# Image Upload & storing the link in the database

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using this form to add the title,link of the image and the text of the article  to the database.
I'm using type="text" for the image link,now,it's getting borring to upload an image on a external image upload service and copy the link.

I want to upload the image with this for and store THE LINK of the image in the database.

The form:

```
<?php if (!$_POST["go"]){ ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="article_title" type="text">
    <input name="article_image_url" type="text"> <!-- i want here type="file" -->
    <textarea name="article_text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
} else {
   $date=date("Y.m.d");
   $title = $_POST["article_title"];
   $image_url = $_POST["article_image_url"];
   $text = $_POST["text"];


$sql="INSERT INTO articles (title,image_url,text,date) VALUES ('$title', '$image_url', '$text', '$date')";

if (mysql_query($sql)){

echo "done";}

else {echo "error<br>" . mysql_error();}}

?>
```

Please help me with this :)

ps:sorry for my English :$

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like he want change the `article_image_url` to be `<input type="file">`. Save image in folder and store the image name to db. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do, and it seems you are clueless about [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/), is add following before you access the first `$_POST` var:

```
$_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);
```

Then you seemingly want to use a file upload for the image. If so change the url field to:

```
<input type=file name=image>
```

This uploaded file will show up in `$_FILES`. Use it like this, preferrably after you've read the other fields from $_POST:

```
if ($img = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) {
     $image_url = md5_file($img) . ".jpeg";
     move_uploaded_file($img, "./upload/$image_url");
     $image_url = "http://www.example.org/where/$image_url";
}
```

There are lot's of security concerns with that. But that's out of scope here, so I hardwired it to `.jpeg`. There's lots of information in the manual and its comments: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php